# GLVis: Linker error "undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributs'"

Tags: xorg

I'm trying to install [GLVis](http://glvis.org/) which has a lengthy list of dependencies (see end of post), all of which I installed, either via `apt-get` or manual compilation. However, I'm getting a linker error when trying to make GLVis. Specifically an undefined reference to symbol '*XGetWindowAttributes*':

```
stan@ubuntu:~/Downloads/glvis-3.1$ make
g++ -O3 -I../mfem-3.3.2 -DGLVIS_MULTISAMPLE=4 -DGLVIS_MS_LINEWIDTH=1.4 -I/usr/include -DGLVIS_USE_LIBPNG -DGLVIS_USE_FREETYPE -I/usr/include/freetype2 -o glvis glvis.cpp -Llib -lglvis -L../mfem-3.3.2 -lmfem -lrt -L -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lpng -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpthread
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: lib/libglvis.a(aux_vis.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:187: recipe for target 'glvis' failed
make: *** [glvis] Error 1
```

`make` did not return any other errors, so that I assume I did not miss to provide any of the required libraries. After quite a bit of purging and reinstalling packages I chose to ask for your help, since I cannot even tell whether the fault is on my side of things. I have very little knowledge about the internals of Ubuntu and X11 and I'd be very appreciative of your kind help.

How could I attempt to solve this problem? This particular error has appeared for other people in contexts I cannot relate to and trying their solutions, if applicable, did not get me anywhere.

I'm on a virtual machine using Ubuntu 18.04 64bit.

---

The instructions for installing GLVis state:

> GLVis is an X11 application and can be built on Linux/Unix systems including
>   Mac OS X using the X11/XQuarz app and under Windows using Cygwin/X.
>
> Besides a C++ compiler, GLVis depends on the following external packages:
>
> - the MFEM library (use the latest release) plus any libraries that MFEM was
>     built to depend on
>     mfem.org
> - the X11, GL and GLU libraries
>     x.org, opengl.org, mesa3d.org
> - the libpng or libtiff library; used for taking screenshots (optional)
>     libpng.org, libtiff.org
> - the FreeType 2 and Fontconfig libraries; used for font rendering (optional)
>     freetype.org, fontconfig.org
>
> There are two build systems, one based on GNU make and one based on CMake, as
>   described below. Choose the one that matches the build system you used to
>   build MFEM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in an old environment variable that is no longer used in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, called **$X11_LIB_DIR**. That doesn't evaluate to anything, and breaks the **mpicc** compiler when **-L** is used.

See below:

```
mpicxx -O3 -I../mfem -I../mfem/../hypre-2.10.0b/src/hypre/include -DGLVIS_MULTISAMPLE=4 -DGLVIS_MS_LINEWIDTH=1.4 -I/usr/include -DGLVIS_USE_LIBPNG -DGLVIS_USE_FREETYPE -I/usr/include/freetype2 -o glvis glvis.cpp -Llib -lglvis -L../mfem -lmfem -L../mfem/../hypre-2.10.0b/src/hypre/lib -lHYPRE -L../mfem/../metis-4.0 -lmetis -lrt -L -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lpng -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpthread
```

Notice the random **"-L"** before **"-lX11"**?

It should be this:

```
mpicxx -O3 -I../mfem -I../mfem/../hypre-2.10.0b/src/hypre/include -DGLVIS_MULTISAMPLE=4 -DGLVIS_MS_LINEWIDTH=1.4 -I/usr/include -DGLVIS_USE_LIBPNG -DGLVIS_USE_FREETYPE -I/usr/include/freetype2 -o glvis glvis.cpp -Llib -lglvis -L../mfem -lmfem -L../mfem/../hypre-2.10.0b/src/hypre/lib -lHYPRE -L../mfem/../metis-4.0 -lmetis -lrt -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lpng -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpthread
```

So, to fix this, change **line #121 in makefile** to read:

```
GL_LIBS = -lX11 -lGL -lGLU
```