# makefile:187: recipe for target 'glvis' failed

Tags: virtualbox, compiling, gcc, make

```
root@hyunsoo-VirtualBox:/home/hyunsoo/Downloads/glvis-3.4# make MFEM_DIR=../mfem-3.4 -j 4

g++ -O3 -I../mfem-3.4 -DGLVIS_MULTISAMPLE=4 -DGLVIS_MS_LINEWIDTH=1.4 -I/usr/include -DGLVIS_USE_LIBPNG -DGLVIS_USE_FREETYPE -I/usr/include/freetype2 -o glvis glvis.cpp -Llib -lglvis -L../mfem-3.4 -lmfem -lrt -L -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lpng -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpthread

/usr/bin/ld: lib/libglvis.a(aux_vis.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

makefile:187: recipe for target 'glvis' failed

make: *** [glvis] Error 1
```

how to solve this problem?
what can i do for slove the error("recipe for target 'glvis' failed')?

Comment: similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035062/glvis-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-symbol-xgetwindowattributs